# Is it ok to run other services on an Exit relay?

Tags: exit-relays, traffic-analysis

The Tor documentation suggests not to host an exit relay on your home network (or at least if it's your only  connection) because all your local traffic will be viewed as coming from Tor as well, and some websites will block it.
Above are all outbound traffics. My question is that is it ok to host other services on a Tor exit relay? Will inbound traffic cause any problem? Tor exit relay info are all public anyway so it shouldn't cause any anonymity issues to my  relay's user right?

Answer (score 1):

> The Tor documentation suggests not to host an exit relay on your home
> network (or at least if it's byour only connection) because all your
> local traffic will be viewed as coming from Tor as well, and some
> websites will block it.

Actually, it's much more than that. I suggest that you read [Tips for Running an Exit Node](https://blog.torproject.org/tips-running-exit-node) before starting to run an exit node.

It probably wouldn't hurt to run a web server, ssh, or anything like that. However, that IP could start getting blacklisted. I would suggest running any extra services on a separate machine or at least leasing a second IP address for that machine and configure those services to only use it and not the IP that the exit node is using.

Comment: I've read it before. It doesn't say much about running extra services on your relay. I'm in Switzerland and the ISP (Fiber 7) is really chill with Tor exits. They even encourage thier users to run it. Furthermore, getting your IP blacklisted does prevent you from accessing some sites, but it doesn't prevent any incoming traffics.

Answer (score 1):

One reason to not run a service on any node is that one could see a correlation between your node and your service. Someone could see that your service is down every time your node goes down.

Comment: They will know the service is down when they visit the service themselves. I don't see the point here.

Comment: Right, they'll see that the service is down in both cases. But if they see the service going down when your exit node is going down they know it's the same node so they know your IP address.